# Go back in time and create branch?

Tags: git, branch

I'm trying to do the following thing in git:

1. Go back a few commits (master branch)
2. Create a new branch
3. Restore the latest commit on the master branch (go forward)

The order is not important, it could be done like:

1. Create a new branch and switch to it
2. Go back a few commits (erase them from the branch history)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand. What's wrong with:

```
git branch newbranch $ID_OF_BRANCH_POINT
```

?

Comment: Nothing, it's actually exactly what I was looking for, I just didn't know it was there. Thanks.

Comment: Aha! Glad to be of assistance.